# My PS3 suddenly says it has the wrong WPA key

Tags: psn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PS3 keeps saying my WPA key is wrong.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24996/ps3-keeps-saying-my-wpa-key-is-wrong)

My PS3 has been perfectly fine then it suddenly claims I have the wrong WPA key but I know its the right one since my PS3 was fine for 6 months. What could have gone wrong?